# Why do I get "Instance has no attribute _caller" error while making post-request to external API using web2py

Tags: python, http-post, urllib2, web2py

I'm trying to fetch data to populate my web2py database from my own API. This works fine when I make the post request from my operating systems default python Interpreter (2.7) but when I run the exact same code in web2py-enviroment I get this error:

```
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute '_caller'
```

Web2Py also runs on same python version. Here's my test-code located in web2py project//models/x_fixtures:

```
import json
import urllib2

if db(db.rftable.id > 0).count() == 0:
    data = {
            'ids': [12, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }
    url = 'https://eo7sjt6hvj.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/tables/getall'
    req = urllib2.Request(url, json.dumps(data), {'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

EDIT:
Entire Traceback of the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/toni/repos/python/web2py/fsttrpg/gluon/restricted.py", line 219, in restricted
    exec(ccode, environment)
  File "/home/toni/repos/python/web2py/fsttrpg/applications/fsttrpg/controllers/default.py", line 14, in <module>
AttributeError: addinfourl instance has no attribute '_caller'
```

My default/controller:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
### required - do no delete
def user(): return dict(form=auth())
def download(): return response.download(request,db)
def call(): return service()
### end requires
def index():
    return dict()

def error():
    return dict()
```

Comment: The instance referred to in the error does not appear in the posted code, and you don't indicate what code it refers to.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added additional details :)

Comment: I still don't see `addinfourl` anywhere; nor does it appear that `x_fixtures` has 14 lines.  If I drop your model file into a web2py instance (replacing the DB call with True), it gets as far as making the Request (which fails, given the bogus URL).

Comment: Thank you for trying it out, edited the url to be a real one.

Comment: If you test it out with correct url, you can maybe see the error is not dependent on the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response` is one of the globals that web2py uses; your code just stomped on it, which breaks the controller.